# How to include a .h file for different subspecs in cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

In my `.podspec`, I have two different `subspecs`. But, they both need to "know" a common `.h` file. How can I do that?

Do I need to factor this `.h` file in a subspec?

Answer (score 1):

Both subspecs can have a `source_files` option. Those subspec's do not know about other subspecs sources so you can include any files there, regardless of overlap.

Take a look at the [`AFNetworking spec`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking.podspec) for an example.

Comment: Did you mean `source_files` option? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Edited. The specs repo is always a good place to look for example syntax.

Comment: Yes it's true. I am a newbie, but the documentation of `cocoapods` is not very enlightening :( to be fair...

Comment: I'm saying to look at https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs for existing podspecs you can model yours after. Also if you think there should be something more in the docs they are open source as well. https://github.com/CocoaPods/guides.cocoapods.org/issues Feel free to submit an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.

```
s.source_files = 'Classes/CBDViewsToolKit.h' 

  s.subspec 'Core' do |ss|
    ss.source_files ='Classes/both/OSView.h'  
  end

  s.subspec 'OSView+CBDFillWithSubview' do |ss|
    ss.dependency 'CBDViewsToolKit/Core'
    ss.source_files = 'Classes/both/OSView+CBDFillWithSubview/**/*.{h,m}'  
  end

  s.subspec 'OSView+CBDSetEnabled' do |ss|
    ss.dependency 'CBDViewsToolKit/Core'
    ss.source_files = 'Classes/both/OSView+CBDSetEnabled/**/*.{h,m}'
  end
```

Since I am a newcomer to cocoapods, let's see if there are other solutions.